# jQuery appending data to a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get data of the form using this:

```
form = $(this).parents('form');
```

And then using jQuery form I send it via:

```
form.ajaxSubmit()
```

But prior to that, I want to append a value to my form. How should I do this?

It is worth mentioning that I cannot access the form html markup to add a hidden input field 
and that's why I need to do it in jquery.

By value I mean a key&value pair, as if belongs to an input.

Comment: you can have an hidden input field and set its value

Comment: I can not access the form for some reason

Comment: in that case we can append it to the form action

Comment: Would you explain it...

Comment: can you share the form's action attribute value

Comment: `<form name="orders" method="post" action="controllers/orders.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it in the url string like

```
form.ajaxSubmit({
    url: 'controllers/orders.php?mykey=' + encodeURIComponent('myvalue')
})
```

---

Or use a dynamic hidden field like

```
var input = form.find('input[name="mykey"]');
if (!input.length) {
    input = $('<input />', {
        name: 'mykey',
        type: 'hidden'
    }).appendTo(form);
}

input.val(myvalue)
```